# How to secure a Post Request and Response in PHP

Tags: php, security, curl

I am using curl post to exchange data between my three sites. I need to secure the data exchange by confirming whether the POST request in sent from either of my three sites.

Right now I have implemented the request header check but the request headers can also be manipulated. Is there a fool proof way to achieve this?

Comment: are you familiar with php sessions and cURL?

Comment: Are you on the client trying to ensure that you are reaching the correct server or on the server trying to make sure that the client is authorised?  Or are you trying to ensure the data inside the request remains secret?  (Or all three.  That would be the best situation.)

Comment: It starts with SSL, which also supports client certificates. If you're looking for public/private key encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working on a RESTful service and also think about how I ensure the communication between service and authorized clients. After lengthy research I decided on the following solution.

Each client (application) has a public ID and a private key. The public ID can be up. The private key, only the client and the service know.

With each request, the client must authenticate it does with HTTP Basic Authentication. The username is the public ID. The password is a SHA1 token. The token is generated by the combination of the public ID, the transmitted parameters and the private key.

When the service receives a request, he knows by the username which client has made ​​this request. It generates a token with the same method and compares it with the password.
Are the two token identical, the client is entitled to make the request. Additionally, it is ensured that the parameters are not manipulated.

Comment: The private key should not be known by the server. That is not how private public key systems work. So the *only* you have in your answer is actually not *only* but *too much*. What you describe is a so called shared-secret. Like a passphrase.

Comment: I wanted to point is that the password is not used in plain text. Sorry if the terms have confused.